# Dynamic reducer creation

Tags: reactjs, redux, flux

Googled that a lot and still didn't find any help.

I'm really new in the react-redux world, so if this is too basic for you guys, please forgive me. My scenario, in a nutshell, is: I have a DASHBOARD component, which renders some COLUMNs components which basically are only one component instantiated multiple times. And here's my problem. How can I make the Column's data different from each other? Having in mind, I'm using Redux.

Today I have a reducer for each column, but that was for testing only, because the user will be able to create columns on the fly, so I can't create reducers on creation time since I don't know how many columns each user will have.

I thought about dynamic reducer creation, is that ok to do? If so, then how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess it's more safe to go with reducer that takes column name as a parameter, so that you're not going to need dynamic reducers creation. That's one way. Another way is to make a special reducer which invokes some kind of "custom dispatcher". The "dispatcher" could accept freshly added reducers and use them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52241350/generic-reducers-actions-in-react-redux/52294952#52294952

Comment: Hi Egiazarov! Thanks for the response, do you mind going further on how would I implement this? I mean, should I make the API call inside the reducer?